# .NET Core self-contained publish not work

Tags: .net-core

I am creating a webapi project on osx 10.12 and publish to linux-64:

```
$dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64
```

and when I run `./dotnet` on linux server(debian9), it throw error to me:

```
$./dotnet

Error:

An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (dotnet.deps.json) was not found:

    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'

    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
```

I am using dotnet core 2.1.3:

```
$ dotnet --version
2.1.3
```

Comment: On the server, did you install the `dotnet-hosting-2.0.4` package?

Comment: no, i publish the program with self contained, it seems do not need install dotnet framework on server again.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: And you named the project `dotnet`? could you try a different name? I think the host executable has logic to determine a run mode based on the name